How can I combine the results of parallel processing of multiple imputation in a single mids object?
I have been trying to do multiple imputation using miceadds (I use the 2l.pmm method which is not available in mice), in parallel. This is the code for the parallel processing:
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(miceadds)

# Set up parallel backend
num_cores <- 30
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# Define the imputation function
impute_function <- function(data, pred_matrix, method, seed) {
  set.seed(569)
  mice::mice(
    data,
    method = "2l.pmm",
    predictorMatrix = pred,
    maxit = 2,
    seed = seed
  )
}


num_imputations <- 5
seeds <- 1:num_imputations

# Run imputations in parallel
imputations <- foreach(seed = seeds, .combine = 'c', .packages = 'miceadds') %dopar% {
  impute_function(data, pred_matrix, method = "2l.pmm", seed = seed)
}

# Stop the cluster
stopCluster(cl)

The object imputations is a list containing each iteration.
How can I combine these iterations in a single mids object like the function
mice(data, method="2l.pmm", predictorMatrix = pred, maxit = 2, seed = 569)

would give?
P.S I tried using the function futuremice but I cannot use it with the 2l.pmm method from miceadds. If you know a way to do that that would be even better I think.

Use mice::ibind(), e.g.,
imp <- imputations[[1]]
for (i in seq_along(imputations)[-1]) {
  imp <- mice::ibind(imp, imputations[i])
}

or
imp <- Reduce(mice::ibind, imputations[-1], init = imputations[[1]])


Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I do get error
Arguments x and y not of class mids
Probably, because the objects in the list are not recognized as mids objects.  Is there something wrong with the initial parallelization code or is there a workaround?

What if you change .combine = c to .combine = mice::ibind?

Turns out latest mice version 3.16.0 added a way to include additional packages for external imputation functions.
Argument package = "miceadds" should be added to the futuremice() function, in order to use 2l.pmm with parallel processing, without the need for foreach().
